# react useCallback() without deps

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Often, `useCallback()` is used for event handlers for memoized components. But in these cases, explicit dep tracking seems unnecessary.

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

function useHandler(fn) {
  const ref = useRef();
  ref.current = fn();
  return useCallback(function() {
    ref.current.apply(this, arguments);
  }, []);
}
```

This function will return a stable reference (not upsetting memo), but also not have a stale closure...and no explicit dep tracking is necessary.

```
function MyComponent() {
   const random = Math.random();
   <OtherComponent onClick={useHandler(() => console.log(random))} />
}
```

These like a very common pattern, yes? Is there anything in the React standard hooks, or common libraries that does this? Or do I need to write my own implementation.